# What is the best practice for a multi-conditional php if statements with variables?

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I have a form which fetched inner variables. Original looks like this:

```
if ($something != 'Some-thing'{
    $code = ' <form id="form" method="post" action="' . $the_url . '">
              </form>';
    return $code;
} else { 
$code = '<form action="https://www.website.com/">
         </form>';
return $code;
}
```

It first checked if variable $something equals a value, if so then first, if not then second.

But then I wanted to add in new fields, with if/else statement to toggle the whole field.

Now, I already have a toggle on the back end which I click a checkbox and it changes `$variable1` to `on` or `off`. See below:

[screenshot of the back end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c844D.jpg)

Then I add this input field which fetches another field to fill it in if it is toggled:

```
<input type="hidden" name="a_variable_1" value="' . $params['a_variable_A'] . '" />
```

Now, I was having trouble putting the `if` statement inside, so I duplicated the whole field. Which was fine for just one extra variable.

But then I wanted to add a second field with an on/off toggle. And this is where things began to get messy.

Here is my code, but it doesn't seem very practical. And if I wanted to add another variable it would just get absurd.

```
if ($something != 'Some-thing' && $variable1 != "on" && $variable2 != "on") {
    $code = ' <form id="payfrm" method="post" action="' . $the_url . '">
              </form>';
    return $code;
} elseif ($something != 'Some-thing' && $variable1 != "on" && $variable2 === "on") {
    $code = ' <form id="payfrm" method="post" action="' . $the_url . '">
                    <input type="hidden" name="variable_2" value="' . $params['variable_B'] . '" />
              </form>';
    return $code;
} elseif ($something != 'Some-thing' && $variable1 === "on" && $variable2 != "on") {
    $code = ' <form id="payfrm" method="post" action="' . $the_url . '">
                    <input type="hidden" name="variable_1" value="' . $params['variable_A'] . '" />
              </form>';
    return $code;
} elseif ($something != 'Some-thing' && $variable1 === "on" && $variable2 === "on") {
    $code = ' <form id="payfrm" method="post" action="' . $the_url . '">
                    <input type="hidden" name="variable_1" value="' . $params['variable_A'] . '" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="variable_2" value="' . $params['variable_B'] . '" />
              </form>';
    return $code;
} else { 
$code = '<form action="https://www.website.com/">
         </form>';
return $code;
}
```

Above, `variable_A` is the value put into the back end for `$variable1` as shown in the screenshot given above. Likewise, `variable_B` is the text value for `$variable2` from the back end.

What is the best way to add the if statement inside? Or how can I revise my code for optimal practice? Ideally I would like to make it easy for me to add in more variables with fields inside the input, without having to have a messy complicated code.

Comment: Why do you have to emit so much markup on the server side?

Comment: When you use `return`, you free yourself from having an `else`, so you could just do: `if(cond1) { return 'string`'; } if(cond2) { return 'string2'; } ...`.

Answer (score 0):

*(Quick review)* - You can start by reducing your conditional tree using common occurences :

```
if ($something != 'Some-thing') {
    if ($variable1 != "on" && $variable2 != "on") {
        $code = ' <form id="payfrm" method="post" action="' . $the_url . '">
                  </form>';
    } elseif ($variable1 != "on" && $variable2 === "on") {
        $code = ' <form id="payfrm" method="post" action="' . $the_url . '">
                        <input type="hidden" name="a_variable_2" value="' . $params['a_variable_B'] . '" />
                  </form>';
    } elseif ($variable1 === "on" && $variable2 != "on") {
        $code = ' <form id="payfrm" method="post" action="' . $the_url . '">
                        <input type="hidden" name="a_variable_1" value="' . $params['a_variable_A'] . '" />
                  </form>';
    } elseif ($variable1 === "on" && $variable2 === "on") {
        $code = ' <form id="payfrm" method="post" action="' . $the_url . '">
                        <input type="hidden" name="a_variable_1" value="' . $params['a_variable_A'] . '" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="a_variable_2" value="' . $params['a_variable_B'] . '" />
                  </form>';
  }
} else {
    $code = '<form action="https://www.website.com/">
             </form>';
}
return $code;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start to generate the code step by step, instead of generating everything within one `then`-block.

First you have to initialize the `$code` variable and then you can add the additional code, when a condition was matched.

At the end, you make only one return with the whole code. Like this:

```
$code = '';
if ($something != 'Some-thing' {
    $code .= ' <form id="payfrm" method="post" action="' . $the_url . '">';
    if($variable1 == 'on')
        $code .= '<input type="hidden" name="variable_1" value="' . $params['variable_A'] . '" />';
    if($variable2 == 'on')
        $code .= '<input type="hidden" name="variable_2" value="' . $params['variable_B'] . '" />';
} else {
    $code .= '<form action="https://www.thewebsiteaa.com/">';
}
$code .= '</form>';
return $code;
```

Comment: Oh I was wondering if I could do this. So if I did that, and multiple `$code`, this will return all the lines in order when I call `$code` at the end?

Comment: Also why is there a dot before the `=` sign? Is that what is required to concatenate all the instances of `$code`?

Comment: Yes. The important thing is, that you use `.=` to concatenate all the strings. At the end, you return the whole string. Be aware that you create with your last `else` an empty form without any action. Please consider if it is necessary to create the form at all in this case.

Comment: did you forget the closing `)` on line 2?

Comment: Going to try your solution when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Since the main complaint is *it gets messy*, to reduce *messiness* you could concatenate the values of your *on|off parameters* and then use a `switch`. Something like this:

```
$params = "$variable1-$variable2";

switch($params) {
  case 'on-on':
    if($something == 'Some-thing') {
      // do a
    } else {
      // do b
    }
    break;
  case 'on-off':
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well, it is more than just messy, because if you add a third variable that makes it even more difficult. I like your idea for simplifying, but if I added a third variable, or even a fourth, it would start to get very long.

Answer (score 0):

English is not good, I can not explain.

```
<input name="variable[1]" value="1">
<input name="variable[2]" value="2">
<input name="variable[3]" value="3">
...


<?php


$var_input ='';

foreach($_POST['variable'] as $key => $val){

  $var_input .= sprintf('<input type="hidden" name="variable_%s" value="%s" />',$key, $val);

}

if ($something != 'Some-thing'){

 $code = ' <form id="payfrm" method="post" action="' . $the_url . '">
           ' . $var_input . '
           </form>';
  return $code;
}else{

$code = '<form action="https://www.website.com/">
         </form>';
return $code;
}

?>
```